# How to calculate totals by week start and end dates based on date column in the table?

Tags: sql-server

my sql server table named timesheet has 4 columns

```
employee_id int
task_start_date datetime
task_end_date datetime
hours_worked int
```

I need to derive week start date and week end date and total hours the employee has worked in that week. My resulting dataset should have 4 columns -
    Week_Start_Date Week_End_Date Employee_Id Total_Hours_Charged

In other words, i need to get total hours charged by each employee for all the weeks from that table. Could anyone please help me write a query for that?

Comment: what have you tried? please post some sample data for testing and your expected result?

Comment: @Siva - thats a good question. I missed it completely, i just noticed the table and found that task_start_date and task_end_date is always same. Looks like this is a weekly timesheet. So i think the query you wrote in your initial reply will work just fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## SQL Server 2005 and above

#### Assumptions:

1. Task start and end date values are always **same**.
2. Week start and end dates are calculated based on the **task_start_date**.

You can use the `DATEPART` function to find the day of the week for a given date and then use `DATEADD` function to provide the output from `DATEPART` as input to calculate the first and last days of the week.

[**Click here to view the demo in SQL Fiddle.**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/2ff4f/1)

#### Script:

The script calculates the week totals hours assuming that week begins on *Sunday* and ends on *Saturday*.

```
CREATE TABLE timesheet
(
        employee_id     int
  ,     task_start_date datetime
  ,     task_end_date   datetime
  ,     hours_worked    int
);

INSERT INTO timesheet
    (employee_id, task_start_date, task_end_date, hours_worked) 
    VALUES
      (1, '20120331', '20120331', 6),
      (1, '20120401', '20120401', 3),
      (1, '20120403', '20120403', 8),
      (1, '20120409', '20120409', 5),
      (1, '20120412', '20120412', 4),
      (2, '20120402', '20120402', 7),
      (2, '20120403', '20120403', 6),
      (3, '20120409', '20120409', 4),
      (1, '20120412', '20120412', 8);

;WITH empworkhours AS
(
    SELECT  DATEADD(DAY
                ,   -(DATEPART(dw, task_start_date) -1)
                ,   task_start_date) AS week_start
        ,   DATEADD(DAY
                ,   7 - (DATEPART(dw, task_start_date))
                ,   task_start_date) AS week_end
        ,   employee_id
        ,   hours_worked
    FROM    timesheet
)
SELECT      week_start
        ,   week_end
        ,   employee_id
        ,   SUM(hours_worked) total_hrs_per_week
FROM        empworkhours
GROUP BY    week_start
        ,   week_end
        ,   employee_id;
```

#### Output:

```
WEEK_START      WEEK_END        EMPLOYEE_ID TOTAL_HRS_PER_WEEK
--------------  --------------  ----------- -----------------
March, 25 2012  March, 31 2012       1               6
April, 01 2012  April, 07 2012       1              11
April, 01 2012  April, 07 2012       2              13
April, 08 2012  April, 14 2012       1              17
April, 08 2012  April, 14 2012       3               4
```